# Robots.txt error with google

Tags: php, html, apache, web, seo

I have this error in my Google Webmaster Tools for add my `sitemap.xml`

> URL restricted by robots.txt

In my robots.txt I have:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /$
Disallow: /
```

It’s for index just my home page not all website.

Comment: Read: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35235?hl=en

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Why do you have the `$` there. And why the `Disallow: /`:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /$
Disallow: /
```

Just change it to this:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

But if you only want it to index the actual index page, then change it to this:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /index.php
Disallow: /
```

Or perhaps do this which changes the order of directives:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
Allow: /index.php
Allow: /$
```

This last example combines your `robots.txt` items, but also reorders them. So it should work as you want it to; just the index page and nothing else.